# Appending time series to existing HDF5-file with tstables

Tags: python, pandas, time-series, hdfs, pytables

Running [TsTables example](https://github.com/afiedler/tstables/blob/master/EXAMPLES.md#load-one-month-of-minutely-bitcoin-price-data) once: everything works. Running second time:

**tables.exceptions.NodeError: group `/` already has a child node named `BPI`**

Makes sense, can not do

```
ts = f.create_ts('/','BPI',BpiValues)
```

since the corresponding node/leaf already exists in the HDF5 tree.

**Question**: how should `TsTable` class be instantiated from a group that already exists? Doing `.getNode('/', 'BPI')` on file handler returns a group, not a table.

Answer (score 1):

Found the function for that in [group.py](https://github.com/afiedler/tstables/blob/master/src/tstables/group.py):

```
tstables.get_timeseries(f.root.BPI)
```

where `f` is the file handler to HDF5 file produced in that [BPI example](https://github.com/afiedler/tstables/blob/master/EXAMPLES.md#load-one-month-of-minutely-bitcoin-price-data).